# Find the values of $a , b$ if $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt{ax^2 + 3bx+5} - 2x =3$

Tags: limits

Find the values of $a$ , $b$  if $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt{ax^2 + 3bx+5} - 2x =3$

Can you please help me solving this

Thank  you

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt{ax^2 + 3bx+5} - 2x= \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{(a-4)x^2+3bx+5}{\sqrt{ax^2 + 3bx+5}+2x} $$

For the limit to exist, $a=4$. Otherwise, it diverges. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you for your reply , why do I have to remove the  x square ?      Can't I work on it while we still have x square in the equation ?

Comment: @BOuchi You can work with it, but if the coefficient of the $x$ square is not $0$, the limit will diverge, because the function your are taking the limit of will diverge.

Comment: what I don't understand , why do I have to simplify the power , I understand the diverging part , but still don't understand why this will cause a diverging

Comment: @Bouchi Here is an simple example $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^2}{x}$ doesn't exist. Similarly,  $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$doesn't exist.

Comment: so the main purpose of the simplification is to avoid having infinity/infinity which is an indeterminate form . right ? even if lim of x^2/x doesn't exist  lim of x does . right?

Comment: No, the limit is $\infty$, as it diverges.

Comment: yes yes limit to infinity that's what i meant

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Multiply by $\frac{\sqrt{ax^2 + 3bx + 5} + 2x}{\sqrt{ax^2 + 3bx + 5} + 2x}$ to get $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\left(\sqrt{ax^2 + 3bx + 5} - 2x\right)\left(\sqrt{ax^2 + 3bx + 5} + 2x\right)}{\sqrt{ax^2 + 3bx + 5} + 2x}$$

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach: for $x\to\infty$,
$$\sqrt{ax^2 + 3bx+5}=\sqrt{a}x\sqrt{1 + \frac{3b}{ax}+\frac{5}{ax^2}}=\sqrt{a}x\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{3b}{ax}+\frac{5}{ax^2}\right)+o(1/x)\right)\\
=\sqrt{a}x+\frac{3b}{2\sqrt{a}}+o(1)\stackrel{?}{=}2x+3+o(1)$$
where we used the fact that $\sqrt{1+t}=1+\frac{t}{2}+o(t)$ as $t\to 0$.

Now it suffices to solve the equations
$$ \sqrt{a}=2\quad\mbox{ and }\quad \frac{3b}{2\sqrt{a}}=3$$
and we find that $a=4$ and $b=4$.

P.S. Since $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt{ax^2 + 3bx+5} - 2x =3$ it is easy to see that $a>0$.